# difference between calling a cunstructor function using new Con and new Con()?

Tags: javascript

I have a chunk of code :

```
function Cons=function () {
    this.a='a';
}

var obj1 = New Cons;  //  {a: "a"}
var obj2 = New Cons(); // {a: "a"}
```

both `obj1` and `obj2` return same object, why ? I mean, what is the difference between creating object using `New Cons` and `New Cons()` ?

Comment: There is no real difference, though the parens are required to pass in arguments.

Comment: There is no difference. The parentheses are optional if no parameters are to be passed to the constructor.

Comment: `new Cons` is syntactic sugar for `new Cons()`